# Unable to write data on realtime database iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to write basic user info like `uid` and `email` of the user to realtime database after registering user. The user is registering but data is not writing to database.

```
func updateDb(){
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let uid = user?.uid ?? ""
        print(uid)
        let reference = Database.database().reference()
        reference.child("userss").child(uid).setValue(["uid": uid, "email": email]){ (err, resp) in
            guard err == nil else {
                print("Posting failed : ")
                print(err?.localizedDescription ?? "")

                return
            }
            print("No errors while posting, :")
            print(resp)
        }

        self.hideProgress()
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure table name is `userss` with 2 s??

Comment: it should create `userss` if not exists. isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I were having the same issue, tried a lot of things then I added `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'` in my pod file and everything goes perfect. So make sure to add it too.

**My Podfile**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'My Garage' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for My Garage

pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to guard user ID, in case if user id is empty reference will not be called.

```
guard let uid = user?.uid else {
 print("ID not found")
 return
}
```

Than make your parameters like this

```
let param: [String: Any] = ["uid": uid, "email": email]
```

than upload values like this

```
reference.child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(params) { (error, ref) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        print("Values updated")
    }
```

Comment: still not adding data into db. log is showing uid of creating user but data is not saving

Comment: no error is printed. is it possible that its because of emulator?